# Getting started with PHP in Eclipse IDE

Tags: php, ide

I am a Java programmer, but recently got a job working with PHP and mySQL. I looked up good IDEs for this (I previously used Netbeans) and Eclipse was recommended.

When I tried to start working, I got the following error message:

```
Error launching 'firstfile'

The debug session could not be started.
Please make sure that the debugger is properly configured as a php.ini directive."
```

I looked this up on Google and tried a bunch of the solutions proposed. I even re-installed Eclipse.

I have the following:

1. eclipse-php-helios-win32 (full)
2. WampServer2.1

My configuration is under Window->Settings->PHP->PHP Executables is:

```
Name: exec-wamp
Executable Path: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.exe
PHP ini file: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.ini
SATI Type: CLI
PHP debugger: XDebug
```

NOTE: I tried to switch debuggers to Zend Debugger and this did not help.

Comment: "Eclipse was recommended" - really?  Over JetBrains' PHPStorm?  I'm surprised.

Comment: @duffymo +1 for knowing that PhpStorm is the best PHP IDE ;)

Comment: @duffymo I'm getting into PHPStorm and it has its own problems. However, I certainly wouldn't go back to eclipse for PHP.  Stick with Netbeans if you don't want to splash out on PHPStorm.  The js support is considerably less buggy in Netbeans than in Eclipse.  Projects with a lot of js regularly crashed Eclipse for me.

Comment: Netbeans is still pretty good with PHP too, btw

Comment: I dunno. I don't want to spend a ton of time configuring another IDE. Would it not be simpler just to get Eclipse working (for now)?

Comment: I'm still confused...not really sure where to go from here...

Comment: phpstorm doesnt look free? now for your error, it looks like you have an error in configuring ur debugger in php.ini on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the resource at http://www.xdebug.org/docs/install#configure-php and make sure you have everything configured as-described.

Specifically:

1. Ensure that your debugger is set up correctly in `php.ini`
2. Uncomment the string in `php.ini`
3. Restart your web-server (if you are on `modphp`)
4. Make sure that in your phpinfo() you have set `xdebug`

Answer (score 0):

Just go to http://www.zend.com/products/studio/downloads and download the "Studio Web Debugger". Follow the instructions given in the Installation guide (http://static.zend.com/topics/Zend-Debugger-Toolbar-Installation-Guide.pdf).
Trick is to choose the right ZendDebugger.dll (or .so) corresponding to your PHP version.

With these steps, you can run your PHP program as a script and the output appears in the console.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Aptana Studio works great for PHP and is built on Eclipse. It can be used as a standalone IDE or as an Eclipse plugin. It gives you all the benefits of Eclipse plus a lot of extra stuff that makes doing web development in PHP, JS, and HTML/CSS a joy. See http://www.aptana.com/

Answer (score -1):

Do you have correct zend_extension variable for debugger?
Use phpinfo, to check.

http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/articles/debugger/os-php-eclipse-pdt-debug-pdf.pdf
Scroll-down to Troubleshooting in the pdf.

Comment: I got the following after running phpinfo():
Configuration File (php.ini)
Path  C:\Windows  
Loaded Configuration File: C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\bin\php.ini  
Scan this dir for additional .ini files  (none)  
Additional .ini files parsed  (none)

Answer (score -3):

I started with NetBeans after using Eclipse for many years. Eclipse is pretty good. Downsides, though, are that many plugins come bundled and don't communicate with the core, as you can see in the error log. :\

You might check out the Aptana build on Eclipse, which is good with JavaScript. PDT (PHP Developer Tools) is also really good for PHP. If you use the two together on Eclipse, though, you'll have a lot of conflicts.

I'd try NetBeans for PHP. By default, it installs all you need for PHP, MySQL, CSS and JavaScript.